# In Delphi how does the OnIncludeItem event work on TOpenDialog?

Tags: delphi

I've been playing around with the TOpenDialog in Delphi XE2, and haven't been able to work out how to make the OnIncludeItem event work.  I want to be able to show files based on their file name (or file size etc).  Has anyone used this event successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TOpenDialog** is an encapsulation of the *Windows Common Dialog* component.  The **OnIncludeItem** event is the encapsulation of the **CDN_INCLUDEITEM** notification mechanism.  [The documentation for this notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains that items which have the **SFGAO_FILESYSTEM** and **SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR** flags set are always included, irrespective of what you return from the **CDN_INCLUDEITEM** notification message (or event, in Delphi).

Further, [the documentation for these **SFGAO** attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) further suggests to me that the **CDN_INCLUDEITEM** mechanism was never intended to be used to filter file system items but rather to exclude things that were *not* part of the file system.

This is confirmed in [another answer to a slightly different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/937484/123487).

Comment: Setting Include := False (or true) in the OnIncludeItem event doesn't seem to do anything - so I think you are right in that it can't be used to filter files.

Comment: I'd expect that on Vista up that this event would not even fire because TOpenDialog is implemented on top of the new common item dialogs and not the legacy common file dialogs.

Comment: In fact what seems to happen, at least for my simple test, is that `OnIncludeItem` never fires, and you get the old legacy dialogs. The worst of all worlds!

Comment: @David.. this is one of those components which I think is trying just a bit too hard to present a uniform programming interface to something that is sufficiently different in it's various guises that the "inconvenience" of having a TCommonItemOpenDialog vs a TOpenDialog would have been worth it.  Trying to figure out how this component behaves - either intentionally or accidentally - under the various settings that can be applied is a recipe for sleepless nights!